# heatdirectory directory dynamic

Tags: msbuild, wix

I want to add a `HeatDirecotry` task to my `wixproj` in `Visual Studio`, but I need the Directory attribute - the source path - will be a variable - a preprocessor variable, so I can supply it dynamically.

Can anyone tell how can I do that?

Thanks!!!

Comment: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/preprocessor.htm read this. as far as the source path. it's usually INSTALLFOLDER

Answer (score 0):

Try the following 
Unload your project and then add the below code in .wixproj file

```
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
         <HeatDirectory DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER" 
                        OutputFile="Source.wxs" 
                        Directory="C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\ComponentsFiles" 
                       SuppressRootDirectory="true" 
                      ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" AutogenerateGuids="true" 
                   ComponentGroupName="SourceComponentGroup" 
                   PreprocessorVariable="var.SourcePath">                             
           </HeatDirectory>
         </Target>
```

and then reload the project. Add the following file  for the preprocessor variable inside the buils tag of the project properties
            SourcePath=C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\ComponentsFiles